# Serialization of class's members

Tags: c#, class, serialization

give me please advice.I have proposed a class for serialization in namespace "Xml_form_application"and it looks this way:

```
namespace Xml_form_application
{
    public class RecordStore
    {
        public MyObject MyObjectProperty;

    }

    public class MyObject
    {
        public string item = "thing";
    }
}

 //Class form2 with button2 to calling this action /serialization)
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
          RecordStore pd = new RecordStore();
          TextWriter tr = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/admin/Dokumenty/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Xml_form_application/Xml_form_application/Cvicna.xml");
          XmlSerializer sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RecordStore));
          sr.Serialize(tr, pd);
          tr.Close();

   }
```

In input there's this xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RecordStore xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

I wanna to have this input with xml code (How way I can attain this result):

```
<RecordStore>
  <MyObjectProperty>
      <item>thing</item>
  </MyObjectProperty>
</RecordStore>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<MyObjectProperty><item>thing</item></MyObjectProperty>` output is *missing* because `pd.MyObjectProperty` evaluates to null.

By default, null values of non-sequence types that would be serialized as *Elements* are omitted by XmlSerializer.

Compare with:

```
RecordStore pd = new RecordStore {
    // It's really a Field, not a Property ..
    MyObjectProperty = new MyObject()
};
```

---

Even though not required, I recommend always using `[XmlRoot]`, [`[XmlElement]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `[XmlAttributes]` attributes, as they can mitigate some re-factoring changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `MyObjectProperty` is `null` and so you don't get that thing. Initialize it to get expected result.

```
RecordStore pd = new RecordStore();
pd.MyObjectProperty = new MyObject();
```